# How to save Webpart property with Contribute permission

Tags: c#, web-parts

This is my code

```
 public string siteURL = string.Empty;
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),        
        //ReadOnly(true),
    WebBrowsable(false),
    WebDisplayName("Columns Filter"),
    WebDescription("Columns Filter Property"),
    Category("Miscellaneous")]        
    public string SiteURL
    {
        get
        {
            return siteURL;
        }
        set
        {
            siteURL = value;
        }
    }
```

but Webpart property cannot save with Contribute permission. Please help me to save property whit Contribute permission.

Thanks
Nguyen

Answer (score 1):

By Default Contributors will not have access. Go to webpart galleries and then Change the permissions for this webpart.

Comment: Thanks. How to fix it for contribute permission can save property ?